# How to read the author, genre, etc infomation from a ASF file via C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, asf

I am developing a small application to catalog my cd rips. don't know how to get these info. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Hi, guys, I have found a Taglib Sharp (http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp) which solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @smwikipedia please do up vote the correct answers

Comment: is that mandatory? anyway, i just did it.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the [ASF specification](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/format/asfspec.aspx) would probably get you started (though there are almost certainly libraries out there to make it easier).